# Should package names be singular or plural?

Tags: object-oriented, naming, packages

Often, in libraries especially, packages contains classes that are organized around a single concept.  Examples:  **xml, sql, user, config, db**.  I think we all feel pretty naturally that these packages are correct in the *singular*.

> com.myproject.**xml**.Element
>   com.myproject.**sql**.Connection
>   com.myproject.**user**.User
>   com.myproject.**user**.UserFactory

However, if I have a package that actually contains a **collection of implementations of a single type** - such as **tasks, rules, handlers, models, etc.**, which is preferable?

> com.myproject.**tasks**.TakeOutGarbageTask
>   com.myproject.**tasks**.DoTheDishesTask
>   com.myproject.**tasks**.PaintTheHouseTask

or

> com.myproject.**task**.TakeOutGarbageTask
>   com.myproject.**task**.DoTheDishesTask
>   com.myproject.**task**.PaintTheHouseTask

Answer (score 425, accepted):

*Use the plural for packages with homogeneous contents and the singular for packages with heterogeneous contents.*

A class is similar to a database relation. A database relation should be named in the singular as its records are considered to be instances of the relation. The function of a relation is to compose a complex record from simple data.

**A package, on the other hand, is not a data abstraction.** It assists with organization of code and resolution of naming conflicts. If a package is named in the singular, it doesn't mean that each member of the package is an instance of the package; it contains related but heterogeneous concepts. If it is named in the plural (as they [often](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html) [are](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.aspx)), I would expect that the package contains homogeneous concepts.

For example, a type should be named `TaskCollection` instead of `TasksCollection`, as it is a collection containing instances of a `Task`. A package named `com.myproject.task` does not mean that each contained class is an instance of a task. There might be a `TaskHandler`, a `TaskFactory`, etc. A package named `com.myproject.tasks`, however, would contain different types that are all tasks: `TakeOutGarbageTask`, `DoTheDishesTask`, etc.

Comment: For a similar question, see http://english.stackexchange.com/q/25713. A _category_ is analogous to the singular and a _type_ is analogous to the plural.

Comment: The very [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html) you provided shows an exception to this rule. `beans` is plural, however `java.beans` contains all kind classes related to JavaBeans.

Comment: Good answer, but I don't agree with the database relation logic. Relations in an ERD are singular because they are showing relationships between entities. Tables are a physical implementation of the relations, and they hold multiple rows, and should thus be plural IMO. The answer to "what is in this table?" is "users" not "user". Granted, it seems that singular naming is more common in the enterprise world (C#, Java) than it is in communities like Ruby, Python, Javascript, and PHP.

Comment: So essentially name a package plurally if it has classes that really do serve different puprposes or whatever, but which are just similarly-themed, and name a package singularly if it just contains classes that heavily focus on coming together as a sort of "meta-class" for a single purpose?

Comment: Also AS3 wouldn't be an exception to the rule, would it?

Comment: @SkyDan's comment points out something very important that is being entirely overlooked here. It appears to me that the plural naming of "java.beans" was actually a mistake, and it should instead have been named "java.bean", singular.

Comment: @VickyChijwani @SkyDan since JavaBeans™ is a trademark, they probably wanted to keep the name as-is to refer to the technology itself, and hence they used `java.beans`.

Comment: From where that quote is taken? "Use the plural for packages with homogen..."

Comment: Should i name a package 1- **helper** or **helpers**.  2- **utility** or **utilities** ?

Answer (score 3):

This probably depends on a specific language. In .NET (C#) it most definitely should be a plural if a namespace-type name collision is likely (the `type name expected but namespace found` error). I've dealt with this, it's not pleasant and results in over-qualifying type names all over the code. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729686/a-domain-entity-called-domain).

Answer (score 2):

IMHO

It depends on whether the package represents a container or a collection.

- com.my.proj.core.view <- collection
- com.my.proj.views     <- container

- com.my.lib.task
- com.my.proj.tasks

- com.my.lib.widget
- com.my.proj.widgets

**IMHO**

- jaba.beans should contains many real beans.
- jaba.bean should be a collection with many 'bean relative' classes in it.

---

I prefer singular, unless it 'must be' plural.

Singular may not always be 'best' but always 'right'.

Answer (score 1):

Naming things is one of the famous three hard problems.

Just as *names of files are part of the user interface*, and so should not contain characters like `U+0004` or nonbreaking spaces, *names of variables are part of the "developer interface"*, and should be chosen to increase understanding, reduce friction and ease development.

In this sort of situation one should consider the following, in this order:

- Don't cause confusion
- Comply with local policy if there is one
- Follow best practices
- Use your own preference

**In this case I don't see it matters very much**

The time you are spending on *making the decision* is better spent on other things.

Just pick one and move on.